# Scrollviewer scrollbars not showing and needs to

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

Why do the scrollbars not appear with the following XAML?

```
<Window x:Class="GridViewsToImagePocApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlna:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width=800">
    <StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer IsEnabled="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <StackPanel>
                <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
                <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="GridView2" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="0 15 0 0" />
                <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="GridView3" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="0 15 0 0" />
                <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="GridView4" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="0 15 0 0" />
                <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="GridView5" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="0 15 0 0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Please try to post your code instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer `StackPanel` is the issue. It measures its children with positive infinity (height in `Vertical` `Orientation` or width in `Horizontal` orientation). Hence the `ScrollViewer` is not restricted in any way, so it expands to fit its content and does not need to display any scrollbars.

Use a [panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/panels-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) that restricts the size of the `ScrollViewer` to the available space instead, like [`Grid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=windowsdesktop-5.0), [`UniformGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) or [`DockPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.dockpanel?view=windowsdesktop-5.0), depending on your requirements.

```
<Grid>
   <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
      <StackPanel>
         <!-- ...your content. -->
      </StackPanel>
   </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```